# Can't get javascript generated html using python & Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get the list of trainings from a link using below Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.cbtnuggets.com/search'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
print(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("table").text)
browser.quit()
```

Mostly, I am only getting the table header as output:

> COURSE TITLE TRAINER RATING VENDOR IT PATH SKILL LEVEL

But this output is not consistent, once or twice (in 20 tries) the entire table was printed (listing all the trainings from the webpage), but I am unable to get a consistent output.

I tweaked the implicitly_wait(30) between 30-60 secs but without resolution. Also I can see that the AJAX contents gets loaded well within the 30 sec timer.

My Requirements:

1. Get the list of trainings
2. Also add the hyperlink of each training page in another column. For e.g. the first training in the table has the link `https://www.cbtnuggets.com/it-training/isc2-cissp-2015`

So the output should have following table headers

- Course Title
- Trainer
- Rating
- Vendor
- IT Path
- Skill Level
- course url (to be extracted from the href tag)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the required content. Whether you wait to get the table or not, it is always there with the headers. However, the tbody content generates dynamically so you should make your script wait for that to be available.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.cbtnuggets.com/search'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
for items in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("table tbody tr"):
    data = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in items.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")]
    print(data)
browser.quit()
```

To make the execution time faster, you can use `BeautifulSoup` in combination with `selenium` like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.cbtnuggets.com/search'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table tbody")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml") #if you haven't installed "lxml" yet, try replacing it with "html.parser"
for items in soup.select("table tbody tr"):
    data = [item.get("href") for item in items.select("a")]
    print(data)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks. That does show the tbody contents, however, how do I get the webpage link to each of the training pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by recreating the XHR API request made on the page, which retrieves the catalogue info, and handling the JSON response. I would welcome suggestions on how to remove the repeated loops over `data`. I thought about using unpacking in a single loop but thought, even if did work, would be hard to follow. It is however, still fast.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

base = 'https://www.cbtnuggets.com/it-training/' 
response  = requests.get('https://api.cbtnuggets.com/site-gateway/v1/all/courses/for/search?archive=false')
data = response.json()
titles = [item['title'] for item in data]
trainers = [item['trainers'][0]['name'] for item in data]
ratings = [item['rating'] for item in data]
vendors = [item['vendors'][0]['display'] if len(item['vendors']) != 0 else 'N/A' for item in data]
paths = [item['paths'][0]['path_label'] for item in data]
skillLevel = [item['difficulty']['display'] for item in data]
links = [base + item['seoslug'] for item in data]

df=  pd.DataFrame(
    {'Course Title': titles,
     'Trainer': trainers,
     'Rating': ratings,
     'Vendor': vendors,
     'IT Path': paths,
     'Skill Level': skillLevel,
     'Course URL': links
    })

print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```